# How to avoid nested callbacks in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using the library [Reactive Network](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork) for Android. I'm an absolute beginner with RxJava, and I'm trying to wrap my head around it. What I am trying to do is:

1] Continously observe changes in the phone's network connectivity state

2] If the phone is connected to a network, check once if there is an internet connection

To do that, I have the following code in Kotlin:

```
    ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(applicationContext)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { connectivity ->
                if (connectivity.state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity()
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe { isConnectedToInternet ->
                                if (isConnectedToInternet) {
                                    Log.d("VED-APP", "Connected to Internet")
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("VED-APP", "Not Connected to Internet")
                                }
                            }
                } 
            }
```

However, this code is ugly and very nested. Is there a way to cleanup this code?

Although the sample is in Kotlin, answers in Java or Kotlin would both be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can filter connectivity.state and next use flatmap operator translate observable to  ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity(). such as :

```
ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(applicationContext)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .filter{it.state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED}
        .flatMapSingle{ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity()}
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext{
             if (it) {
                Log.d("VED-APP", "Connected to Internet")
             } else {
                Log.d("VED-APP", "Not Connected to Internet")
             }
         }
         .subscribe()
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got an error on the line `.flatMap{ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity()}` I updated my post with a screenshot.

Comment: change `.flatMap{ReactiveNetwork.checkInternetConnectivity()}` to `.flatMapSingle { ...` as `checkInternetConnectivity()` produces a `Single` rather than an `Observable` as was being handled upstream

Comment: @Alan Wang, I know this is out of the scope of the original question, so feel free to not answer, but would there be a way to also call `Log.d("VED-APP", "Not Connected to Internet")` if `it.state` equals `NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED`

Comment: @Roymunson  i think you can log it use doOnNext  operator before filter, or log it in filter  then return false or true.

Comment: You could try using switchIfEmpty(t -> Log.d("VED-APP", "Not Connected to Internet")) next to filter. If filter returns empty then this log will be printed.